# Remove rows which have an empty string in a specific column

Tags: r

I have the command `df[(df$column_name == ""), ]` which gets all rows which contain `""` (empty strings) in the column named column_name. How do I do the opposite?

That is, how do i get all rows which do NOT contain `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `!=`

```
df[(df$column_name != ""),]
```

Comment: It wasn't my vote, but I am guessing that it was because you answered a super easy question that showed no research effort.

Comment: @RichardScriven I understand that, but to a newbie, everything in a new language would be difficult to grasp until somebody give them some direction